# apache spark deploying on amazon emr

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

My command:

> aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-10366NQM2PJDC --steps
>   Type=spark,Name=SparkWordCountApp,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false,--num-executors,5,--executor-cores,5,--executor-memory,20g,s3://wordCount.py,s3://input-bucket/inputFile.txt,s3://output-bucket/],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
>
> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   AddJobFlowSteps operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::503059920414:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole/i-052a3cd61db3879d9
>   is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:AddJobFlowSteps on
>   resource:
>   arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-2:503059920414:cluster/j-10366NQM2PJDC

Can somebody have any pointers on this? I am new to spark.

Comment: Does the user, whose access keys and secret keys you are using, has access to EMR service?

Comment: Yes it does. I can submit jobs through GUI but not through command line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using your Instance profile role `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` to make calls to EMR to add STEPS to a cluster. The error means, your instance profile role's `policy` do not allow access to do this `Action` of elasticmapreduce:AddJobFlowSteps. In fact the default managed policy attached to this role `AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role` will not have this access.

So, you will need to [add](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html) a policy to your role EMR_EC2_DefaultRole to allow  elasticmapreduce:AddJobFlowSteps Action.